# Stress vs stressed vs stressful

Tags: vocabulary

As Cambridge says, stressed (out) means worried and nervous.
I want to know if it has the same meaning as "stressful", and "stress" used as a noun. In other words:
Are these three phrases the same? Or, better to say, do they carry exactly the same meaning? If not, what is their difference between them (if they are all used correctly)? Is one of considered more common than the others?

1. I'm stressed (out).
2. I have stress.
3. I'm stressful

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not.

"I'm stressed out" is normal English.

"I am under stress" would be the normal way to express the second one, though it means less than the first one -- "stressed out" covers only the case where you are under stress and it's getting to you.

"I'm stressful" means that you *cause* stress, not that you suffer it.

So that, for instance, if you take a stressful job, every day when you go there, you are under stress, and if the stress gets to you, then you are stressed out.

Comment: Thanks a million. So, as a related question: stress vs stress out, as Longman expresses: "She's stressing about her exams". With this meaning, do we need to use "stress out" and not "stress"? If not, what would be the difference between the two?